# how to write or condition in ejs?

Tags: node.js, ejs

How can i write **or** condition in ejs template.I tired the following

```
     <%if (user ===0 || user ===1) { %>
      <div id="main_div">
          My content over here
      </div>
        <% } %>
```

it will satisfy the first condition but not the second one.

Comment: That's how you would write it... what's wrong?

Comment: maybe your "user" variable be String type. in this case use only two ==

Answer (score 4):

if you use the strong equality (=== instead of ==) ensure that your variable contains integer.

```
"1" == 1 // true
"1" === 1 // false
```

Or use parseInt around your variable

```
<%if (parseInt(user) ===0 || parseInt(user) ===1) { %>
```