# OR condition with EJS?

Tags: html, if-statement, ejs

**Both of these statements work:**

```
  <% if(currentUser.collegeLevel === "High School") { %>    
  <h1>  They have a High School Degree </h1>
  <% } %>


  <% if(currentUser.collegeLevel === "Associates Degree") { %>    
  <h1> They have an Associates Degree </h1>
  <% } %>
```

**This statement does NOT work**

```
<% if(currentUser.collegeLevel === "Associates Degree" || "High School") { %>    


 <h1> They have either a High school or Associates Degree</h1>

  <%  } %>
```

**why does the OR function not work?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to write or condition in ejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168887/how-to-write-or-condition-in-ejs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because the OR is not comparing against anything else..

It should look like this:

`if(currentUser.collegeLevel === "Associates Degree" || currentUser.collegeLevel === "High School")`